# Calculate max date with oData V4

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, odata

I am trying to get the date that records with various status codes were last created. I am issuing this query:

```
http://localhost/FTPOrdersoDataService/odata/FTP_ORDER_STATUS_LOG?$apply=groupby((STATUS), aggregate(FTP_ORDERS_ID with max as lastCreated))
```

The following error is returned":

```
{
"error": {
"code": "",
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"innererror": {
"message": "Argument types do not match",
"type": "System.ArgumentException",
"stacktrace": "   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Bind(MemberInfo member, Expression expression)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.AggregationBinder.BindSelect(IQueryable grouping)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.ApplyQueryOption.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, ODataQueryContext queryContext)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
}
}
```

If I change the request to:

```
http://localhost/FTPOrdersoDataService/odata/FTP_ORDER_STATUS_LOG?$apply=groupby((STATUS), aggregate(FTP_ORDERS_ID with max as lastCreated))
```

then it functions properly, so obviously the issue is with the CREATEDDATE field. CREATEDDATE is defined as TIMESTAMP(6) in Oracle and is defined as DateTime in my EF model.

Is there a secret for making max (and other aggregation functions) work with dates?

Comment: This appears to be a known bug with OData/WebAPI. https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/912

Comment: Try to use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime

Answer (score 1):

> Tested in `Microsoft.AspNet.OData.7.4.1`

In the past there were issues with this, however the OData implementation has evolved, you can now use the following query syntax to cast the field to a type that is supported by the standard `EnableQueryAttribute`:

`aggregate(cast(CREATEDDATE, Edm.DateTimeOffset) with max as lastCreated)`

```
http://localhost/FTPOrdersoDataService/odata/FTP_ORDER_STATUS_LOG?$apply=groupby((STATUS), aggregate(cast(CREATEDDATE, Edm.DateTimeOffset) with max as lastCreated))
```